# python pandas extracting numbers within text to a new column

Tags: python, pandas, extract

I have the following text in *column* A:

```
A   
hellothere_3.43  
hellothere_3.9
```

I would like to *extract* only the numbers to another new column B (next to A), e.g:

```
B                      
3.43   
3.9
```

I use: `str.extract('(\d.\d\d)', expand=True)`  but this *copies* only the 3.43 (i.e. the exact number of digits). Is there a way to make it more generic?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["hellothere_3.43", "hellothere_3.9"]})
df["B"] = df["A"].str.extract("(\d*\.?\d+)", expand=True)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                 A     B
0  hellothere_3.43  3.43
1   hellothere_3.9   3.9
```

Answer (score 0):

I think string split and apply lambda is quite clean.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["hellothere_3.43", "hellothere_3.9"]})
df["B"] = df['A'].str.split('_').apply(lambda x: float(x[1]))
```

I haven't done any proper comparison, but it seems faster than the regex-solution on small tests.